# How To Config TOMCAT7 and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I have got a big problem with the TOMCAT7 local server.
I followed this guide =>  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html. In order i did:

1)`copy the JDBC Driver's jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib`.My "$CATALINA_HOME/lib" is in /usr/share/tomcat7/lib (i think so, i'm not sure). I copied there the file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar`.

2)I created a new MySql user and followed the rest mySql instruction:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO javauser@localhost
    ->   IDENTIFIED BY 'javadude' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> create database javatest;
mysql> use javatest;
mysql> create table testdata (
    ->   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ->   foo varchar(25),
    ->   bar int);
```

3)I modified the `context.xml` file locate in the position `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/META-INF` in the following mode

```
<Context>

    <!-- maxActive: Maximum number of database connections in pool. Make sure you
         configure your mysqld max_connections large enough to handle
         all of your db connections. Set to -1 for no limit.
         -->

    <!-- maxIdle: Maximum number of idle database connections to retain in pool.
         Set to -1 for no limit.  See also the DBCP documentation on this
         and the minEvictableIdleTimeMillis configuration parameter.
         -->

    <!-- maxWait: Maximum time to wait for a database connection to become available
         in ms, in this example 10 seconds. An Exception is thrown if
         this timeout is exceeded.  Set to -1 to wait indefinitely.
         -->

    <!-- username and password: MySQL username and password for database connections  -->

    <!-- driverClassName: Class name for the old mm.mysql JDBC driver is
         org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - we recommend using Connector/J though.
         Class name for the official MySQL Connector/J driver is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
         -->

    <!-- url: The JDBC connection url for connecting to your MySQL database.
         -->

  <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>

</Context>
```

i added the `<Resource ...>` part.

4) I created the web.xml file in the same dir `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/META-INF`. the file contains the following code:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <description>MySQL Test App</description>
  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

5)Then I created in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT location the dir DBTEST and inserted here the file test.jsp with this code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/TestDB">
select id, foo, bar from testdata
</sql:query>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>DB Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2>Results</h2>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
    Foo ${row.foo}<br/>
    Bar ${row.bar}<br/>
</c:forEach>

  </body>
</html>
```

before starting the test.jsp i downloaded this 4 file .jar from `http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/`

```
taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar
 taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
 taglibs-standard-compat-1.2.5.jar
 taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
```

then (always follow instruction) i created the dir lib in `var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/META-INF` 
 ===>> `var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/META-INF/lib`
inside of this i've copied the 4 .jar file.

NOW `http://localhost:8080/DBtest/test.jsp` RETURN

```
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

and once time to two return

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.DBtest.test_jsp
```

Comment: jars go in `/lib` not `/META-INF/lib` AFAIK

Comment: Thanks, i'v copied te 4 files  *.jar in   /lib  (not var/lib, only lib). There is the same problem! Are correct the 4 files .jar ???

Comment: By "/lib" I mean `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib`, see the doc: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: Sorry, i haven't been clear: in ROOT dir i have the following subdir:

Comment: DBtest and META-INF only